# bash script to append string to multiple files in same directory

Tags: bash, append

Is there a way to write a BASH script that will append a string to every file in a directory?

e.g., I want to append the string "test" to every .html file in the current working directory I'm in; something like:

```
echo "test" >> *.html
```

But of course this doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in *.html ; do
    echo "test" >> $f
done
```

Comment: Better to put "$f" surrounded by quotes, specially if you have weird filenames (eg: with spaces)

Answer (score 5):

[tee](http://ss64.com/bash/tee.html) is good for these sorts of things.

```
echo "test" | tee -a *.html
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i.bak '$a append' *.html
```